# Como usar for each em array de arrays(matriz)?

Tags: java, matriz, foreach

Tendo o array de arrays:

```
 int matriz[][] = new int[1][1]
```

Como faço para usar o for each (for(int count : array)) para percorrer suas linhas e colunas?

Answer (score 4):

A nameira de percorrer o array usando "foreach" é a seguinte:

```
int matriz[][] = new int[1][1];

int valorRecebido = 0;

for (int[] vetor : matriz) {
    for (int elemento : vetor) {
        valorRecebido = elemento;
    }
}
```

Veja que dessa maneira, todas as linhas e colunas da matriz são percorridas e acessadas pela variável `elemento`.

Perceba que o loop mais externo retorna um vetor de uma dimenção por iteração e o loop mais interno retorna um elemento, novamente por iteração. Dessa maneira, todo o vetor é percorrido.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, mas eu queria saber como fazer isso usando "for each", aquele "for(int i : array)".

Comment: Opa verdade! Me dê uns minutos

Comment: Beleza, obrigado.

Comment: Por favor, caso a resposta esteja correta, marque o "check" verde que aparece abaixo do contador da resposta. Obrigado :)